# cannot find -linet in omnet 4.6

Tags: omnet++

I want to run a simulation in Omnet 4.6 which uses inet.
When compiling, following error occurs.

```
Creating executable: ../out/debug/src/EnergyCellFMU_TwoHouseholds.exe
D:\omnetpp-4.6\tools\win32\mingw32\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -linet
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:154: recipe for target '../out/debug/src/EnergyCellFMU_TwoHouseholds.exe' failed
make[1]: *** [../out/debug/src/EnergyCellFMU_TwoHouseholds.exe] Error 1
make[1]: Target 'all' not remade because of errors.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/d/Simulation_energy-cell-concept_omnet4.5/energy-cell-concept-simulation/OMNet/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

Does anyone know where the problem could be?
I set inet in the project references.

Comment: Did you compile INET?

Comment: Yes, and I also added it under makemake/link